# The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

The model item passed into the ViewDataDictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[website.Models.main]', but this ViewDataDictionary instance requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[website.Models.List]'

Here i have joined four tables using EF include method.This error occurs while i'm doing this method.

controller :

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            
            var listAll = db.main
                .Include(x => x.Person)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity)
                .ThenInclude(x => x.Country)            
                .ToList();
return View(listAll);

        }
```

View :-

```
 @model List<website.Models.List>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; 
    }
```

Models :- I don't know what i did wrong here please give me any solutions

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace website.Models
{
    public class List

    {
        public mainmain{ get; set; }
        public Persons Person { get; set; }
        public other other{ get; set; }
        public Entities Entity { get; set; }
        public Countries Country { get; set; }
        public int countryId { get; internal set; }
    }

    public class main
    {
        public int id{ get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
        public int? PersonId { get; set; }
    
    }

    public class Person
    {
        public Person()
        {
            main= new HashSet<main>();
        }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FirstNameEn { get; set; }
        public string FirstNameAr { get; set; }
        public string SecondNameAr { get; set; }
        public string HomePhonePart1 { get; set; }
        public string HomePhonePart2 { get; set; }
        public ICollection<main> main{ get; set; }
    }

    public class Other
    {
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public string FatherReligio { get; set; }
        public bool? Fatherless { get; set; }
        public DateTime? FatherDeathDate { get; set; }
        public bool? Motherless { get; set; }
  
     
    }

    public classEntity
    {
        public Entity()
        {
            Persons = new HashSet<Persons>();
        }
       
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string ResponsibleName { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Pobox { get; set; }
        public string PhonePart1 { get; set; }
        public string PhonePart2 { get; set; }
      
        public ICollection<Persons> Persons { get; set; }
    }

    public class country
    {
        public country()

        {
           Entity = new HashSet<Entities>();
            Persons = new HashSet<Persons>();
        }
       
        public string NameEn { get; set; }
        public string NameFr { get; set; }
        public string NameSp { get; set; }
        public string NameUr { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Entities> Entity { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Persons> Persons { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

try to parse the items into your own List object

```
public IActionResult Index()
{       
    var listAll = db.main
                    .Include(x => x.Person)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Entity)
                    .ThenInclude(x => x.Country)            
                    .ToList();
    
    List<website.Models.List> newList = new List<website.Models.List>();
    foreach(var item in listAll){
          website.Models.List listItem = new website.Models.List();
          listItem.countryId = item.countryId;
          //add your remaining fields
          newList.Add(listItem);
    }

    return View(newList);
}
```

Comment: .Its working but in the view i can't get proper data which is i need ..can i change anything in the view ??

Comment: you need to loop through the list as following 
@foreach(var item in Model){ 
//print items 
}

Comment: Gracias, amigo a mí me funciono tu código ya estaba desesperado. Saludos

Answer (score 1):

The `listAll` is a list of the `main` object, you need to use the corresponding type to accpet it in your razor page:

```
@model List<website.Models.main>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index"; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

PopulateAssignedSpecialtyData(doctor);
PopulateDropDownLists();

```
    ViewData["DepartmentId"] = new SelectList(_context.Departments, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["DoctorTypeId"] = new SelectList(_context.DoctorTypes, "Id", "Name");
    ViewData["BloodGroupId"] = new SelectList(_context.BloodGroups, "Id", "Name");
    return View(doctor);
}

// POST: Doctors/Create
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create(
    [Bind("ID,FirstName,MiddleName," +
    "LastName,CityID,Designation,DepartmentId,DoctorTypeId,Gender,BloodGroupId," +
    "HospitalVisitTimeFrom,HospitalVisitTimeTo,HospitalConsultingDuration,OnlineVisitTimeFrom," +
    "OnlineVisitTimeTo,onlineConsultingDuration,PresentAssignment," +
    "ShortBiography,DoctorEmail,DoctorQualifications,DoctorAchievements,Addresses,DoctorDocuments,DoctorSpecialties,DoctorPositions,DoctorExperiences,DoctorMemberships,")]
    Doctor doctor,

    string[] selectedOptions,
    List<IFormFile> theFiles
    )
{         
    try
    {

        UpdateDoctorSpecialties(selectedOptions, doctor);
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {

            await AddDocumentsAsync(doctor, theFiles);
            _context.Add(doctor);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();


            //Create Users when Doctor create in admin login
            var userManager = _serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
            if (userManager.FindByEmailAsync(doctor.DoctorEmail).Result == null)
            {
                IdentityUser user = new IdentityUser
                {
                    UserName = doctor.DoctorEmail,
                    Email = doctor.DoctorEmail
                };

                IdentityResult result = userManager.CreateAsync(user, "doctor123").Result;

                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Doctor").Wait();
                }
            }
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
        }
    }
    catch (RetryLimitExceededException /* dex */)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes after multiple attempts. Try again, and if the problem persists, see your system administrator.");
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("", "Unable to save changes. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.");
    }


    //Validation Error so give the user another chance.
    PopulateAssignedSpecialtyData(doctor);
    //Get the full city object for the Doctor and then populate DDL
    doctor.City = await _context.Cities.FindAsync(doctor.CityID);
    PopulateDropDownLists(doctor);
    return View(doctor);
}

// GET: Doctors/Edit/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var doctor = await _context.Doctors
       .Include(d => d.City)
       .Include(d => d.DoctorDocuments)
       .Include(d => d.DoctorSpecialties)
       .ThenInclude(d => d.Specialty)
       .AsNoTracking()
       .SingleOrDefaultAsync(d => d.ID == id);
    if (doctor == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    PopulateAssignedSpecialtyData(doctor);
    PopulateDropDownLists(doctor);
    return View(doctor);
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).